# check if value is integer or double in objective c

Tags: objective-c, types, double, type-conversion

I have a case where I should get the elements from an array and I do not know if the type is double or integer.

[array objectAtIndex:2]

and the problem is that I can not identify the type. If i knew the type I simply would perform:
[[item objectAtIndex:2] intValue] or
[[item objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue]

Is there any way to detect that?

Br,
Gzim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for the [`-objCType` method](http://file:///Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleSnowLeopard.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/objCType).

Basically, it returns a string describing the type contained in the NSNumber.  The Objective-C runtime documentation has more information on the type codes.

*However*, it is quite odd to have a design where the type is unknown.   I would suggest that a better solution -- possibly an interesting question -- would be to avoid the ambiguous type in the design of your application.

Comment: I read the reference document over and over, and somehow kept missing objCType. Don't know how that happened, most likely was too late at night for me.

Answer (score 0):

NSString* type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[valueInQuestion objCType]];

This will equal "d" if it is a double and "i" if it is an integer.